# Display info message on INITIALIZATION

Tags: abap

I want the user to notice that the report he's currently using is deprecated and replaced by another one. Therefore I'll need to have a popup like an info message on program start.

But when I try to run my code like this:

```
INITIALIZATION.
    MESSAGE i355(zz).
```

The message only appears in the status bar.

This approach would look okay from user side:

```
INITIALIZATION.
    DATA: w_mes TYPE string.
    MESSAGE i355(zz) INTO w_mes.
    CALL FUNCTION 'POPUP_TO_DISPLAY_TEXT'
      EXPORTING
        textline1 = w_mes.
```

But in fact it's very messy.

Is there a smoother way to display an info message on program start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [behavior matrix of the `MESSAGE` statement in Dialog Processing](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abenabap_message_dialog.htm), that is not possible. You might want to move the statement to a different section, e. g. `START-OF-SELECTION`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DISPLAY LIKE` for a message that is originally of type `E` to achieve what you want but then the users will not be able to execute this deprecated version at all.

```
 INITIALIZATION.
   MESSAGE e184(sabapdocu) WITH 'Sorry, Batory!' DISPLAY LIKE 'I'.
```

Such a message will be displayed as a popup.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: From the initialization event, `MESSAGE e184(sabapdocu) WITH 'Sorry, Batory!' DISPLAY LIKE 'I'.` displays the dialog but does not affect the program flow. That is, because the message is type `e`, program execution is terminated from the initialization event.

Comment: My apologies... you did indeed.

Answer (score 0):

One can imagine that this is not allowed to preserve both the ability to call report programs using `SUBMIT` from all contexts(i.e. batch, rfc, update) and to allow external subroutine calls(`PERFORM ABC IN PROGRAM XYZ`).

In instances where this sort of thing is required, perhaps it is best to configure a transaction code(using SE93) to call the program in some way such that the message is displayed.

Here's a quick example using a local class:

```
CLASS lcl_selcr_mess DEFINITION.
PUBLIC SECTION.
METHODS
  start.                                                "#EC CALLED
ENDCLASS.  

CLASS lcl_selcr_mess IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD start.
    MESSAGE i001(00) WITH 'Deprecated...' DISPLAY LIKE 'I'.
    CALL SELECTION-SCREEN 1000.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

[image: Method of a class(OO Transaction)]

If you feel this approach is obtrusive, I suspect this can also be done by creating a "dummy" screen which only displays the message, then passes flow to the selection screen. Create a dialog transaction to call the dummy screen.